# React Jest MSW server not running/working

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, msw

Hello guys i have been stuck with this task for very long time and yet couldn't figure out after checking the docs and other resources in online.

So i have this setup with Jest and MSW but i think the msw server not running at all.

```
   let url = "/api/v1/267/1285/property/search/Bet?searchAll=true";
const server = setupServer(
    rest.get(url, async (req, res, ctx) => {
        req.url.searchParams.get("searchAll")
        ctx.delay(1000)
        return res(
            ctx.status(200),
            ctx.json([
                {
                    cadastralId: "04901000140007",
                    street: "Bet",
                    postalCode: "02150",
                    city: "Espoo",
                    buildingModels: [],
                    buildingIds: null
                }
            ])
        );
    })
);

beforeAll(() => server.listen());
afterAll(() => server.close());
afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers());


test("Valuation List Page tests", async () => {
        render(<ValuationListPage/>)
        await user.type(screen.getByTestId('search-input'), 'Bet');
        await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => screen.getByTestId('circle-spinner'));
        expect(screen.getByText("Bet")).toBeInTheDocument()
    }
)
```

I expect when the mock fetch gets triggered the spinner to be shown but when i check in the logs it seems that its not even rendering atleast in the test and it gives this error:

```
 TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="circle-spinner"]
```

Ive also tried to do add some text and try with `getByText` but its still not working , thats because seems that the server mock is not being called at all :\ .

the component itself looks liek this:

```
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [isNationWide, setIsNationWide] = useState(false);
    const [propertyList, setPropertyList] = useState([]);

    let controller = new AbortController();
    const handleSearchChange = async (searchTerm: string) => {
        console.log("I RUN")
        if (search && search.length > 2) {
            setIsLoading(true);
            let url = "/api/v1/" + props.user?.organizationId + "/" + props.portfolioId
                + "/property/search/" + searchTerm + (isNationWide ? "?searchAll=true" : "");

            if (controller)
                controller.abort();

            controller = new AbortController();

            try {
                const results = await axios.get(url, {
                        signal: controller.signal
                    }
                )
                setPropertyList(results.data.sort((a: valuationListBuilding, b: valuationListBuilding) => (a?.buildingModels?.length || 0) < (b?.buildingModels?.length || 0) ? 1 : -1))
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(`URL:${url} , error: ${error}`)
            } finally {
                setIsLoading(false)
            }

        } else {
            setPropertyList([])
            setIsLoading(false)
        }
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        const delayDebounceFn = setTimeout(() => {
            handleSearchChange(search)
        }, 500)

        return () => clearTimeout(delayDebounceFn)
    }, [search, isNationWide])
```

and rendered like so:

```
 {isLoading ? <CircleLoader height={35} width={35}
                                                       className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mt-5"/> : propertyList.length ?
                                <ValuationListTable properties={propertyList}
                                                    user={props.user}
                                                    sortList={(key, isAsc) => sortList(key, isAsc)}/> :
                                <h6 className="text-muted text-center mt-5"><i
                                    className="fa-solid fa-triangle-exclamation mx-2"></i>{l("valuation_view.list.no_result")}
                                </h6>}
```

The CircleSpinner also has in it data test id.

```
 <div className={props.className || ""} data-testid="circle-spinner">
```

Versions:

```
   "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
   "@testing-library/react": "^12.0.04",
   "jest": "^27.5.1",
   "jest-canvas-mock": "^2.3.1",
   "jest-environment-jsdom": "^27.5.1",
   "msw": "^0.39.2",
```

Comment: Expect your DOM output to figure out what is wrong there. Unfortunately, the current question is too broad and doesn't contain all the necessary information while containing many unnecessary details.